# Visual Studio Include Project Macros shortened

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, macros, include-path, project-settings

I have some default project include macros in Visual Studio 2012 (C++) (Project Properties/VC++ Directories/Include Directories). Instead of just using for example $(SomeMacroRootPath) I want to change the value of "Include Directories" to another one, for example: $(SomeOtherRootPath)/sdk/Include;$(SomeOtherRootPath)/sdk/Include2

&(SomeMacroRootPath) includes several(!) different default pathes for example:
C:\Programm Files (x86)\name\appdata... that are really long. 
Because of that, the the "string/value" I can see in the list if I press the Macros Button in the settings tab (that Button that shows me the list of all Macros) are cut off. Nothing happens if I resize the window or the table column thing at the top.

Unfortunately I need to see all pathes that &(SomeMacroRootPath) contains.

Is there a cmd echo command or is there any chance to look at the full "string" of the macro/variable/string?

I don't know exactly where the macros are defined or where they come from.

Kind Regards

Comment: This sounds like your project is using something called "property sheets". I'm not sure about the extension in VS 2012: Can you spot any `.vcprops` or `.vcxprops` file in your solution directory? That might be the place to search for the macro values.

Comment: I use property sheets but that Macros I want to see in full length is not a user defined macro, it is a "Environment" macro. I don't know the word for it. I can't find it unter System Evnironment Variables. So it is some sort of project Environment Variable(?).

For Example if i create a new console win32 apllication project and take a look under properties/include directories -> macros. There is a for example $(ExcludePath) that is very long and cut off for me. (Another example $(Path) or $(SourcePath). Where do they come from or where can I see the full string value?

Comment: On a command line type `set` to see all defined environment variables. Maybe it's there?

Comment: @foraidt No, unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a workaround by myself.
I created a Post-Build Event

```
Command Line: echo $(SomeMacroRootPath)
Use In Build: Yes
```

Now Visual Studio prints the full path into the output without cutting it off after I rebuild the project.

It would be nice to just see it in the settings when I resize the column. But okay, things are never easy :)

Kind Regards
Nisi